# How to determine the type of an extra in a bundle held by intent?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

I am trying to pass arbitrary data to a `BroadcastReceiver` through its `Intent`.

So I might do something like the following

```
intent.putExtra("Some boolean", false);
intent.putExtra("Some char", 'a');
intent.putExtra("Some String", "But don't know what it will be");
intent.putExtra("Some long", 15134234124125);
```

And then pass this to the `BroadcastReceiver`

I want to iterate through `Intent.getExtras()` with something like `keySet()`, but I would also like to be able to get the value of the key without having to hard-code calls to methods like `.getStringExtra()`, or `.getBooleanExtra()`.

How does a person do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the following code to get an object of any time from the `Intent`:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Object value = bundle.get("key");
```

Then you can determine `value`'s real type using `Object`'s methods.

Comment: The `get(key)` method is deprecated.
What is the newer alternative?

Answer (score 4):

You can browse thye keys without knowing the type of the values using `keySet()`. It returns you a set of `String` that you can iterate on (see [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#keySet%28%29)).

But for the values, it is normal that you have to use a typed method (`getStringExtra()`, `getBooleanExtra()`, etc): this is caused by the fact Java itself is typed.

If you would like to send data of arbitrary types to your `BroadcastReceiver`, you should either:

- convert all your extras to `String`s before sending them, and retrieve all of them as `String`s :

  ```
  intent.putExtra("Some boolean", "false");
  intent.putExtra("Some char", "a");
  intent.putExtra("Some String", "But don't know what it will be");
  intent.putExtra("Some long", "15134234124125");
  ```
- or use the `get()` method of the `Bundle` that returns `Object`s (see [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#get%28java.lang.String%29)):

  ```
  Object o = bundle.get(key)
  ```